# Able to run java application on one system, but not on other

Tags: java, swing, java-7, twitter4j

I am facing a strange situation with my java swing application. In my pc(win-7 x64 and jre-7), it is working fine.I am able to run the jar file on my system, but on a windows xp machine with jre7 installed, it gives the following error trace:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\HOME\Desktop\TweetTweetAsMuchYouTweet_jar>java -jar Tw
eetTweetAsMuchYouTweet.jar
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing
or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/
secret, and the system clock is in sync.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0276a2ab
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-0276a2ab], statusCode=401, message=null
, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:16
2)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.j
ava:61)
        at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java
:98)
        at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthoriza
tion.java:122)
        at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthoriza
tion.java:104)
        at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:2
98)
        at Account.getAccessTokenAfterAuthentication(Account.java:45)
        at Account.<init>(Account.java:33)
        at AddFormWin$1.actionPerformed(AddFormWin.java:75)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If we note the line:

```
Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing
or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/
secret, and the system clock is in sync.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

The authentication is failing due to invalid consumer key/secret. But then why the same app on windows 7 machine, is running perfectly?

Note that in my app, I am using the oob([PIN based](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization)) authentication using Twitter4j(v-3.0.5).

Being a java developer myself, I am quiet surprised with this as java is known for its platform independence. So is there anything wrong with the platform independence of java?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like Java VM or Windows OS issue.  I would suspect there is something to do with oob implementation or the wrong PIN was entered. I assume the PIN needs to be entered for each machine.

Comment: The browser window asking for pin did not open. I think the problem is like: "and the system clock is in sync." May be because the system clock is not in sync thats why it is giving me the error.